# How to use Typescript and Interfaces when passing props down through React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I'm passing down a pretty large array of objects through several React components. I was wondering, what is the syntax for writing the types of all the properties in each object (the objects are nested several times)?

I currently have interfaces like below. These are two components, MainContent, which passes props down into Chart:

MainContent component:

```
interface ComparatorTypes {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface DataTypes {
  jobId: string;
  jobTitle: string;
  descriptionUrl: string;
  totalCompensation: number;
  baseSalary: number;
  longevityPay: number;
  specialPay: number;
  allowances: number;
  paidTimeOff: number;
  holidays: number;
  retirementBenefit: Array<{
    formula: string;
    details: any;
  }>;
  healthBenefit: Array<{
    premium: number;
    details: any;
  }>;
  remoteWork: {
    isAllowed: string;
    details: any;
  };
}

interface QueryTypes {
  agencyName: string;
  id: string;
  data: DataTypes[];
}

interface params {
  comparatorData: ComparatorTypes[];
  queryData: QueryTypes[];
}

export default function MainContent({ comparatorData, queryData }: params) {
  return (
    <S.MainContentComponent>
      <Header />
      <Summary comparatorData={comparatorData} />
      <Chart queryData={queryData} />
    </S.MainContentComponent>
  );
}
```

and Chart component:

```
interface ComparatorTypes {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface DataTypes {
  jobId: string;
  jobTitle: string;
  descriptionUrl: string;
  totalCompensation: number;
  baseSalary: number;
  longevityPay: number;
  specialPay: number;
  allowances: number;
  paidTimeOff: number;
  holidays: number;
  retirementBenefit: Array<{
    formula: string;
    details: any;
  }>;
  healthBenefit: Array<{
    premium: number;
    details: any;
  }>;
  remoteWork: {
    isAllowed: string;
    details: any;
  };
}

interface QueryTypes {
  agencyName: string;
  id: string;
  data: DataTypes[];
}

interface params {
  // comparatorData: ComparatorTypes[];
  queryData: QueryTypes[];
}
export default function Chart({ queryData }: params): JSX.Element {
...
```

You can see how redundant it is to be naming these giant, several-times-nested interfaces before every component that uses this array of objects. Is this normal for Typescript? Is there a better way to do something like this? Or does all this data need to be typed upon being passed down through every component?

Comment: Sounds like your actual problem is [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling).

Comment: Have you tried exporting the interfaces from one file and importing them in the other? So you’d only need to define them once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What forces you to define these identical interfaces explictly for each component?

On the contrary, factorizing them would be the normal choice: that way, they are defined in a single place (single source of truth), and by importing them, you explictly say that you re-use the exact same types.

```
// Chart.tsx
export interface QueryTypes {
  agencyName: string;
  id: string;
  data: DataTypes[];
}

export interface DataTypes {
  jobId: string;
  jobTitle: string;
  // etc.
}

export default function Chart({
  queryData
}: {
  queryData: QueryTypes[];
}) {}

// Main.tsx
import Chart, { QueryTypes } from ".Chart";
import Summary, { ComparatorTypes } from "./Summary"; // Same for ComparatorTypes

export default function MainContent({
  comparatorData,
  queryData
}: {
  comparatorData: ComparatorTypes[];
  queryData: QueryTypes[];
}) {
  return (
    <S.MainContentComponent>
      <Header />
      <Summary comparatorData={comparatorData} />
      <Chart queryData={queryData} />
    </S.MainContentComponent>
  );
}
```

Comment: this seems like the right way to go. Although, shouldn't I define the types at the top level, where (in my app) I'm getting the data out of an API? The types seem like they should be defined at the point the data comes into the app, and imported into lower-level components, rather than the other way around

Comment: It depends on your actual situation. If you adapt your app to already structured data, then indeed, you could do it that way. On the other hand, if your components require a composition of data coming from different sources, then it could be more relevant to have each component define its own required type, as shown above. And you can have every step in between. Some projects separate all interfaces into their own folder.

Comment: thanks very much for the help, I've made an interfaces folder!